# module 'grpc' has no attribute 'insecure_channel'

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to do a connection through grpc using:

```
import grpc
import class


def main():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = class_pb2_grpc.ClassStub(channel=channel)
    list_data(stub)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
AttributeError: module 'grpc' has no attribute 'insecure_channel'
```

I am running this code in a docker with `python 3.8.10` and this packages installed:

```
protobuf==3.18.0
grpcio==1.41.0
grpcio-tools==1.41.0
```

**EDIT**
Also tried under grpc.aio using:

```
channel = grpc.aio.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
```

And it returns:

```
AttributeError: module 'grpc' has no attribute 'aio'
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html#create-channel) has the function under `grpc.aio`, have you tried that?

Comment: @JanWilamowski yes, it returns `AttributeError: module 'grpc' has no attribute 'aio'`

Comment: very strange, since it's clearly part of the Python code: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/__init__.py#L2156

Comment: @JanWilamowski yes, the same happens for secure channel under aio, or without aio :S

Comment: My point was, perhaps your Docker container doesn't actually have to correct code installed. Have you double-checked whether the package is installed correctly and is accessible in Python, e.g. by printing `dir(grpc)`?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Thanks for the suggest. I just found what happens. We have a test file caled grpc in the root directory. I renamed it as it was some old test and its finding the correct code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it worked here also !